# Variable value null in powershell string

Tags: powershell

I am using below code in PowerShell. Unfortunately it is not picking up `$Startinghash` and `$lastHash` value. If I pass value directly, code is working fine.

Not Working :-

```
$StartingHash = "f116bcce5cc0701cb0b5a673bc4ce9f723050f04"
$LastHash = "2870d215c7201e7cf65c71d4d0e732078b3bda31"

git log --pretty=format: --name-only $StartingHash..$LastHash | sort | uniq | grep -i '".sql"' > C:\Ashish\data\sqlRB.txt
```

Working :-

```
git log --pretty=format: --name-only f116bcce5cc0701cb0b5a673bc4ce9f723050f04..2870d215c7201e7cf65c71d4d0e732078b3bda31 | sort | uniq | grep -i '".sql"' > C:\Ashish\data\sqlRB.txt
```

I think somehow variable value is not set.

```
Write-Host git log --pretty=format: --name-only $StartingHash..$LastHash | sort | uniq | grep -i '".sql"' > C:\Ashish\data\sqlRB.txt
```

Output :-

```
git log --pretty=format:--name-only f116bcce5cc0701cb0b5a673bc4ce9f723050f04..2870d215c7201e7cf65c71d4d0e732078b3bda31
```

Comment: @matt when i say its not working that means files C:\Ashish\data\sqlRB.txt is empty.

Comment: What is the output of just this then? `git log --pretty=format: --name-only $StartingHash..$LastHash` or `git log --pretty=format: --name-only "$StartingHash..$LastHash"`

Comment: @Matt `git log --pretty=format: --name-only "$StartingHash..$LastHash"` worked when I tested it. AFAICS your updated answer was correct. Voted to undelete.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Does that mean the quotes were required? Possibly the further filtering and redirection is the issue?

Comment: @Matt Yes. Without quotes: no output. With quotes: same output as with literal hashes.

Comment: @Matt its working after adding quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot speak for your Git code but, as [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) points out there is whitespace inserted in your `--name-only` string. You can see this when you type:

```
Write-Output  $StartingHash..$LastHash
```

or

```
Write-Host  $StartingHash..$LastHash
```

---

What you can do is enclose those values in quotes so that PowerShell sees it as a single string without any whitespace or unanticipated formatting.

```
git log --pretty=format: --name-only "$StartingHash..$LastHash" | ....
```

Comment: If definitely not interpreted as range operator. Try this: `write $StartingHash..$LastHash`. It does not produce any error.

Comment: @PetSerAl Crap. That is what you meant from your comment. Was my answer right but my assumption wrong

Comment: @PetSerAL it gives output f116bcce5cc0701cb0b5a673bc4ce9f723050f04
..2870d215c7201e7cf65c71d4d0e732078b3bda31 which is correct